# How to optimize c# code to select highlighted option from word table

Tags: c#

I have multiple word document (office 2003), one doc contains 100 quiz questions. One table contain one question. More than 250k words in one document. I am using this code to get correct selected option for the question. I am extracting the data from word table. It in c# language using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word. My code is working and it is taking almost 7 minutes to execute. Is there anything I can do to improve it?

```
//check highlighed option       
List<string> Text = new List<string>();
List<string> highlightOptionText = new List<string>();
string output = String.Empty;
bool highlight = false;
int count = 0;
foreach (Range r2 in doc.Words)
{
    count++;

    if (highlight == true && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(r2.Text))
    {
        highlightOptionText.Add(r2.Text.Trim());
        highlight = false;
    }

    if (r2.HighlightColorIndex == WdColorIndex.wdBlack)
    {
        //r2.Find.Highlight = 0;                        
        //output = r2.Text;
        highlight = true;
    }

    // if (count > 20000) { break; }
}
// watch.Stop();
//var elapsedMs = watch.ElapsedMilliseco10
```

Yes i am stuck with 2003 word doc.I am unable to read selected option from table Table t = doc.Tables[iCounter]. Is openXML sdk is good for document and table reading.I am looking at openxml and soon i will update. I am reading table data from this code.

```
 for (int iCounter = 1; iCounter <= doc.Tables.Count; iCounter++)
            {
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Table t = doc.Tables[iCounter];
                Range r = t.Range;


                Cells cells = r.Cells;

                for (int i = 1; i <= cells.Count; i++)
                {
                    Cell cell = cells[i];
                    Range r3 = cell.Range.FormattedText;

                    string txt = r3.Text.Replace("\r\a", "");
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt))
                    {
                        fileData.Add(txt);
                        // Response.Write(r3.Text); //for testing purpose
                    }

                    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(cell);
                    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(r3);
                }}
```

Comment: Are you stuck with using Word 2003 documents? Can you use .docx format instead of .docx? Why do you need Interop in the first place? You know how that works right? It uses COM to interact with a running Word instance. Are you sure you can't  get away with using a library such as [DocX](https://docx.codeplex.com/) that natively understands .docx files?

Comment: Would `Parallel.ForEach` help?